# Selecting between timestamps pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Hello I cannot understand why this code does not select rows between dates. It shows me same dataset from first date 2004. Here is my code below:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.read_csv('time_series_15min_singleindex.csv',header=0,index_col=0,parse_dates=True)  
df=DataFrame(df1,columns['utc_timestamp','DE_solar_generation_actual','DE_wind_onshore_generation_actual']

df['utc_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['utc_timestamp'],utc=True)

start_date=pd.to_datetime('2008-12-31',utc=True)
end_date=pd.to_datetime('2009-01-01',utc=True)
df[df['utc_timestamp'].between(start_date,end_date)]
df.plot()
```

[image: Dataset sample]

Answer (score 0):

You forget assign back, use:

```
df = df[df['utc_timestamp'].between(start_date,end_date)]
```

Comment: says no nuumeric data to plot

Comment: empty dataframe

Comment: @AliaghaNadirli - empty datafrmae means there is no matched values, in sample data are 2018 values so possible.

Comment: sample is from 2004 until 2020